# Changing TabView(selection:) via @Published variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a tab view with tagged items.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var tabController = TabController()

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $tabController.selectedTab) {

        HomeView()
            .tabItem{
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))

                Text("Home")
        }.tag(0)

        ...
}
```

I have an `ObservableObject` that has a `@Published selectedTab` variable and a function to change it.

When I call the function, it correctly prints the index of the tab I want to switch to, but the tab does not switch. Does anyone know why?

```
class TabController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab = 3

    func changeTab(tabIndex: Int) {
        self.selectedTab = tabIndex
        print(selectedTab)
    }
}
```

Instead of `changeTab(tabIndex:)` I have also tried directly changing `selectedTab`.

Edit: I am calling the changeTab(tabIndex:) like this:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var tabController = TabController()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {

                  Button(action: {self.tabController.changeTab(tabIndex: 2)}) {
                      HStack {
                          Image(systemName: "bubble.left.fill")
                              .buttonIconModifier()
                          Text("Switch Tab")
                      }
                  }.modifier(ButtonStyle())
             }
         }        
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I could replicate your code all works fine here. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

Comment: Strange. Only thing I didn't specify above was how I'm calling changeTab - like this:

```@ObservedObject var tabController = TabController()

Button(action: {self.tabController.changeTab(tabIndex: 2)}) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "bubble.left.fill")
                            .buttonIconModifier()
                        Text("Button Text")
                    }
                }```

Comment: If your Button is in body, then I did almost the same.

Comment: Would you show code of another view from where/how you call function? And how it relates to posted `ContentView`?

Comment: I added it above, thanks! @Asperi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a mistake

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var tabController = TabController() // << 1st controller
```

and

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var tabController = TabController() // << 2nd controller
```

your views use *different* instances - `DetailsView` change 2nd, but `ContentView` listen for 1st.

They need to use *one* instance. I asked *how they relates*, because the fix is **to pass tabController** from one to another, or **share** via `EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: So this works for me too when the Button is us in ContentView (your TestSwitchTabOnPublished)

But I'm calling the function from another view, where it does not work. Thanks, we seem to have narrowed it down.

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution!